# When to use .NET Generic Host's Run, Start and WaitForShutdown

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-hosted-services, ihostedservice

I use the .NET [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) (to run a `BackgroundService`). All the examples I've seen ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0)) use `host.Run[Async]`, so I use that and it works for me.

However there are a number of related lifetime methods:

- Run / RunAsync
- Start / StartAsync
- WaitForShutdown / WaitForShutdownAsync

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#manage-the-host-lifetime) state:

> The difference between Run* and Start* methods is that Run* methods wait for the host to complete before returning, whereas Start* methods return immediately.

I understand that. I tested it and that is exactly what happens.

But the docs continue:

> The Run* methods are typically used in console apps, whereas the Start* methods are typically used in long-running services.

I don't understand that. My use case is a long-running service (a "background" service which runs forever until I stop it), but if I use the "Start*" methods then the app exits immediately.

*When would that be the preferred option, and how would it be used?* I don't understand the difference in these use cases, and there's no real example explaining them. Similarly, when would one use the "WaitForShutdown*" methods?

Comment: This means that your application needs to do something else in its main thread and that the hosted services are truly *background* services that work on the side. Perhaps it reads input from stdin, processes it and needs to shut down the background services when it receives a termination sequence or command

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, your comment was an "Aha!" moment for me. I misunderstood the meaning of "background" service for .net. I don't have a "main" worker service accompanied by "background" services, rather, I have a main app which runs forever, until I send it a SIGINT / SIGTERM. From your comment, I assume my use case is not a "background" service, but rather a forever-running "console app", and so I should be using `Run*`.

Comment: But that raises an interesting question: assume a background service as you've explained it. Would one have a "main app", and also "background services" run via the generic host, *at the same time*? So in `Program` one would start both of those things, separately? The docs don't cover this idea, as you've explaned it, but your explanation makes more sense to me.

Comment: Yes - if you use RunConsoleAsync, the services start but the main thread listens for Ctrl+C /Ctrl+Z keystrokes, or SIG_TERM, SIG_KILL on Linux. When those are detected, it calls IApplication...Stop to notify the services to stop gracefully. In a Windows service application the main thread may be listening for command events like stop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks... Your comments in that other question from earlier today suddenly make much more sense! :-)